# A language outside the Boolean closure of stochastic languages

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, probabilistic-automata

Stochastic languages, that is, those accepted by probabilistic automata, are known to not be closed under intersection, union, concatenation, and morphism, even on unary languages.

I have two questions about the Boolean closure of the class of stochastic languages:

1. Is this class closed under morphisms or concatenation?
2. Can we show that  $\{a^{2^n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not in it?

Many thanks!